# Exception while parsing string to document object

Tags: java, xml

I try to bild document object from string and append it into element but I get exception **java.io.FileNotFoundException: project folder path\org.xml.sax.InputSource** in this line: `Document constantDocument = docBuilder.parse(
String.valueOf(new InputSource( new StringReader( xmlAsString ) )));`.

My code looks like this:

```
Element infoElement = document.createElement("information");
String xmlAsString = "..."; //xml in string format
Document constantDocument = docBuilder.parse(
String.valueOf(new InputSource( new StringReader( xmlAsString ) ))); //java.io.FileNotFoundException
infoElement.appendChild(constantDocument);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: FileNotFoundException is pretty clear

Comment: `String.valueOf(new InputSource ....)` I'm not sure that this makes sense.

Comment: if you mean suntax, its intelliJ correction.

Comment: No, I mean semantic, not syntax. It doesn't make sense to create a String from an `InputSource` object. You won't get what you want. And I also don't see your logic behind that. You have a String, try to read it with a `StringReader` wrapped by an `InputSource` just to get another String (which _should_ have the same content as `xmlAsString`)? Why don't you pass `xmlAsString` directly into `docBuilder.parse(..)` (if that method expects XML as String)?

Comment: @Tom: docBuilder.parse(String) expects a URI (some location) for a document to be parsed ...

Comment: You are missing file.

Comment: @Tom if I pass string directly i get "java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol"

Comment: *"if I pass string directly i get "java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol""* Well, then it's time for you to read the documentation to understand what you library actually expects from you. The answer from Exception_al quotes the corresponding paragraphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason is given here in the [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html) :

> public Document parse(String uri)
>                  throws SAXException,
>                         IOException
>
> Parse the content of the given URI as an XML document and return a new
>   DOM Document object. An IllegalArgumentException is thrown if the URI
>   is null null.

You are providing a String, and Java is looking to fetch the file at the given String / URI and hence the Exception ...

Based on your attempt, the closest you could use is :

> parse(InputSource is)
>
> Parse the content of the given input source as
>   an XML document and return a new DOM Document object.

So changing the `.parse` to below should solve your problem :

```
Document constantDocument = docBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlAsString)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Found what I was looking for:

```
DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource is = new InputSource();
is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader("<root><nod1></node1></root>"));

Document doc = db.parse(is);
```